# SQL equivalent of MySqlDbType enumeration values?

Tags: mysql, .net

I can't find it in the documentation, is there anything that converts the numeric values of the **enumeration** to string values usable in **sql queries** and vice-versa?

for instance

```
MySqlDbType.Int32 = 3 = "INTEGER"
```

or

```
MySqlDbType.VarChar = 253 = "VARCHAR"
```

etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such thing in MySQL.  What do you want it for?  Similar information can be found in the pseudo-table `information_schema.COLUMNS` for each column in each table:

```
data_type = 'varchar'
character_maximum_length = 255
column_type = 'varchar(255)'
character_set_name = 'latin1'
```

etc.

Comment: I want it for my mysql wrapper class so i can create tables and such OOP style